# How to do async operation in a thread or in a task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I need to do some operation that need to be async (like writing something to a database, and reading something from it at the same time, deserialize what I read from it, do something with those data...etc) but I need to either do that on a thread, or on a task, so that I can do other things during all that executing.

Moreover, if it could be possible to like, always read the database on one hand, and on another hand writing data in it, it would be great, I'm pretty sure it's possible, but I'm not sure about how to achieve it, and with what library / tools / functions...etc

I'm working on a console application

I tried few things like just async method with some await, but I don't really understand the order of execution between all that, the problem is also that I don't really understand to `async` / `await` keywords, and how `Task` works, but I tried a bit.

What I'm working on is actually 2 `Task.Run`, one that have the writing data in database method, and another `Task.Run` that read the database, the problem is that inside both these method, I have function that are `async`, and then, they need to be awaited somewhere, therefore the call to the writing data or the reading data need to be awaited as well, but I don't know how to make `Task.Run` `async`

```
static async Task Main(string[]args)
{
// Those two tasks need to run at the same time
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Need to be awaited
        var writer = WritingDatabase();
    }

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Need to be awaited as well
        var reader = ReadingDatabase();
    }
}

public async Task<List<Code>> ReadingDatabase()
{
      List<Code> listCode = new List<Code>();
      // Some code
      listCode.Add(await database.ReceiveMessageAsync());
      return listCode;
}
```

The code above is an example, there could be some error in it, but the functional of my code is there

Comment: Link to Task.WaitAll docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually that's how you wait all tasks to be finished asynchronously ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
await Task.WhenAll(myArrayOfTasks);
```

And to await inside `Task.Run` just pass asynchronous delegates ([some read](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html)):

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
});
```

Also, it is helpful to read about why in practice you want to avoid `Task.Run`: [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) and [more examples](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html). In short, you **should not wrap blocking APIs with `Task.Run`**, it makes no sense, since the underlying thread will be blocked anyway. And a good design for non-blocking APIs is to return `Task`, so you don't need to run a new one anyway.

Comment: You use up a Thread, which is a precious resource, made up of Ram and CPU time, and require context switches. Single Threaded is likely more efficient, unless you actually are CPU bound.

Comment: From what i understand, even if single threaded would be much more efficient, i don't though of any way to handle it with single thread in my case, if there is one, why not, but i don't think of anything right now. @astef Thanks for the answer, helped me a lot

Comment: @astef Why would more CPU cores make your Hard Disk spin faster? Why would more CPU time make your PCI-E m.2 nvme data transfer finish earlier? I also DO know that Tasks are not Threads. But Task.Run uses ThreadPool, look up the source code. You should read Stephen Cleary's blog posts on the subject, starting with https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html and then continue on https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html

Comment: I've read all that you linked and i've also encountered his example before you linked it, and i also agree with him even if i know little, even in my real code i can't really think of any way to avoid Task, and fake async, i mean, how could i do operations on data that i still don't have ? the method that retrieve data is async, so i just await this one, and that's all. Maybe i'm doing things wrong, if i do so just tell me, i'm seeking for improvements

Comment: @Luxior the only improvement we're discussing here is what @Paulo did in his answer - use tasks returned from async methods instead of `Task.Run` new tasks. But I'm not insisting on using `Task.Run`, my sample had a different goal in mind. At this point, I'm sure we have enough context on this problem here.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var tasks = new[]
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Need to be awaited
            var writer = WritingDatabase();
        }),

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Need to be awaited as well
            var reader = ReadingDatabase();
        })
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have `Task`-returning APIs, you can just do:

```
static async Task Main(string[]args)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(WritingDatabase, ReadingDatabase);
}
```